# Why isn't there a UX.SE Careers page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

UI/UX Designer and Developer positions are becoming more and more popular and companies are trying to recruit people left and right. I think it would be great to make a page similar to the [Stack Overflow Careers page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) for UI/UX specific careers.

Has this idea been considered at all?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=user+experience

Comment: As rr1g0 points out, there are a fair number of UX jobs on the list...though the site isn't well set up for listing UX expertise and it's a bit frustrating to dig through from that mindset in my opinion. I gave up on trying it rather quickly.

Comment: Yeah - searching for user experience near me comes up with 4 jobs that are absolutely *not* anything to do with user experience and are *all* about software engineers. This is immediately sends signals to me that SO Careers is not where I need or want to look for UX jobs unless something radical changes to focus on true relevance.

Comment: @RogerAttrill Same here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't any reason that I'm aware of, other than it hasn't been done yet.  I think it would be a great idea though.

Comment: I can't wait until UX.SE is a viable source to seeing how much you contribute to the UX sphere, just like SO is used now days.

Comment: @Majo0od isn't it already?

Comment: I wish I could say yes, but in the "professional" world, the people I've worked for never have heard of the site.

Comment: Most non-developers that I've worked with haven't heard of StackOverflow either.  But I get your point.  It may be that SO answers specific questions about implementation, whereas UX.SE doesn't.  I'm not sure if that's a good or a bad thing though.

Comment: Yeah, I guess time will tell. I've made an effort to tell everyone I've worked with about UX.SE - so far going well. I know one day when I'm a manager, I will always check to see if potential employees have a profile and see how they handle questions.

Comment: the name is too cumbersome.  UX.SE?  What is this, an online comic? ;)

Answer (score 7):

> ***Disclaimer**: This is my personal opinion as an employee of Stack Exchange. This is not an official company stance.*

First, you should go read [the great post Joel Spolsky wrote about the history and future of Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Careers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/) Joel wrote it after Stack Exchange closed it latest funding round with Andreessen Horowitz last month and it does a great job summarizing where the company has come from and where its looking to go.

This quote near the end sums up the direction of Stack Overflow Careers:

> I believe [Stack Overflow Careers] is, bar-none, the single best job board for developer candidates, which should automatically make it the best place for employers to find developer talent. There’s a LOT more to be done to serve developers here and we’re just getting warmed up.

While designers are increasingly in-demand, developers are all the more in-demand. The Careers team is just getting started in how we can deliver the best online resource for helping developers find jobs that they love. Once we've figured that out, maybe we'll move into other areas.

That said, Careers does offer a number of [UX Design](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=UX&type=any&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles), [Product Design](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%22Designer%22), and [other various design positions](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%22Designer%22). Why? Because while those may not be "developer-centric", they assist and work with developers regularly (typically).

Comment: Thanks, and it does seem to be improving.  However, several commenters on the OP and I didn't get any jobs in the UX or user experience searches that were actually UX design jobs in our areas.  In particular, the UX query gave me 8 results within a 100-mile radius (much larger than is practical here).  All 8 were dev jobs.  While my area is not as big for UX as NYC or Boston and most of its "UX" jobs have production-level dev responsibilities, it is still a major metro area with at least some true UX design positions within about 20 miles of me.